# Counting a root's children in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table with 3 columns:

1. item ID 'ID'
2. parent ID 'ParentID'
3. item name 'Title'

Now, how should I count how many children a Root has?

Comment: Thanks Mat for the correction :)

Comment: If you want to count descendants, this is your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340696/counting-number-of-children-in-hierarchical-sql-data

Comment: You could see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server/959821#959821

Comment: @Benoit - Or the OP could just see the answer on this page!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T
WHERE ParentID = @ParentID
```

If you want descendants not just immediate children you would need a recursive CTE.

```
;WITH R AS
(
SELECT ID
FROM T
WHERE ParentID = @RootID
UNION ALL
SELECT T.ID
FROM T
JOIN R ON R.ID = T.ParentID
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM R
```

Comment: Yes Martin, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I need to count all the children of children..

Comment: As of PostgreSQL 9.5.1, you need to write RECURSIVE after the WITH.

Comment: @Rodrigo this is a SQL Server question (per the tag)

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. But that may be useful for someone.