# Count the people in the entire chain of command

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

[Counting number of children in hierarchical SQL data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340696/counting-number-of-children-in-hierarchical-sql-data)

This post counts direct reports at each level, but I am wanting to count the complete subordinate chain. Basically, how do I count the ENTIRE number of people in the chain of command? For each and every person.

I'm getting a count, but it's not right.

Here's a sample dataset with a basic chain of command. The real dataset has about 2,500 rows (people), with multiple branches spanning about 7 levels. The server is SQL Server 2012 (I have no say in that matter).

*SAMPLE DATA*

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'[tmpPeople]', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [tmpPeople];

CREATE TABLE [tmpPeople]
(
    [PositionID] [float] NULL,
    [PreferredName] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [ManagerPositionID] [float] NULL
) 
GO

    
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person A', 1, 0)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person B', 2, 1)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person C', 3, 1)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person D', 4, 2)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person E', 5, 3)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person F', 6, 4)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person G', 7, 5)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person H', 8, 6)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person I', 9, 7)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person J', 10, 8)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person K', 11, 3)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person L', 12, 3)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person M', 13, 11)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person N', 14, 11)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person O', 15, 13)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person P', 16, 12)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person Q', 17, 12)
INSERT [tmpPeople] ([PreferredName], [PositionID], [ManagerPositionID]) VALUES (N'Person R', 18, 14)
```

*WHICH PRODUCES THIS*

SELECT * FROM tmpPeople

| PositionID | PreferredName | ManagerPositionID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person A | 0 |
| 2 | Person B | 1 |
| 3 | Person C | 1 |
| 4 | Person D | 2 |
| 5 | Person E | 3 |
| 6 | Person F | 4 |
| 7 | Person G | 5 |
| 8 | Person H | 6 |
| 9 | Person I | 7 |
| 10 | Person J | 8 |
| 11 | Person K | 3 |
| 12 | Person L | 3 |
| 13 | Person M | 11 |
| 14 | Person N | 11 |
| 15 | Person O | 13 |
| 16 | Person P | 12 |
| 17 | Person Q | 12 |
| 18 | Person R | 14 |

*CTE QUERY*

```
;WITH ChildrenCTE AS (
   SELECT PositionID, PreferredName, ManagerPositionID, 0 AS n
     FROM tmpPeople
    WHERE PositionID NOT IN (SELECT ManagerPositionID FROM tmpPeople
                              WHERE ManagerPositionID IS NOT NULL
                            )
    UNION ALL
   SELECT d.PositionID, d.PreferredName, d.ManagerPositionID, n+1
     FROM ChildrenCTE cte
     JOIN tmpPeople d ON d.PositionID = cte.ManagerPositionID
    WHERE n < 20
 )

SELECT cte.PositionID, cte.PreferredName
     , SUM(cte.n) AS children
  FROM ChildrenCTE AS cte
 GROUP BY cte.PositionID, cte.PreferredName
 ORDER BY  positionID
```

*WHICH PRODUCES THIS*

| PositionID | PreferredName | children |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person A | 23 |
| 2 | Person B | 4 |
| 3 | Person C | 13 |
| 4 | Person D | 3 |
| 5 | Person E | 2 |
| 6 | Person F | 2 |
| 7 | Person G | 1 |
| 8 | Person H | 1 |
| 9 | Person I | 0 |
| 10 | Person J | 0 |
| 11 | Person K | 4 |
| 12 | Person L | 2 |
| 13 | Person M | 1 |
| 14 | Person N | 1 |
| 15 | Person O | 0 |
| 16 | Person P | 0 |
| 17 | Person Q | 0 |
| 18 | Person R | 0 |

*THE PROBLEM*

- Test #1: No one person can have more people in their chain of command than there are people in the dataset. I.e. max = 18 people. One person can only report to one person.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many children does "Person I" have?  Isn't the answer to that 0, the same as "Person J"?  Your expected results look incorrect.  Explain why "Person I" has 1 child in your expected result.  If that needs to be corrected, please correct the rest of the results in the question.

Comment: Also, why is "Person A" missing in your expected result?  Isn't that the top level manager with the most total subordinates?

Comment: This is an organisational hierarchy. So yes, there will be a "head of everyone". And the lowest person anywhere will have 0 reports. Let me fix that.

Comment: Your expected result is still wrong, since the last two people are not connected directly.  The result I posted appears to be correct.  Notice 10 is connected to 8 and 9 is connected to 7, not 10 to 9 to 8 to 7.

Comment: Note: You have other problems in your test data, if you expected the hierarchy to be a tree with a single sequential branch of people, top to bottom.  I've provided a second test case which corrects the data and shows your expected result, given that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated logic:

Start the search from all nodes (each as a separate root) and find all children of each root.  Set (n = 0) for the root node and (n = 1) for each child of that root.  Once done, just SUM(n) over each root.  We could also COUNT(*)-1 without needing n (this solution also shown below).

Here's a fiddle ([the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=e387eb59a57759de467327b79e03ffa9)) with the new data.

The SQL:

```sql
WITH ChildrenCTE AS (
       SELECT PositionID AS RootID, PreferredName AS RootName, PositionID, PreferredName, ManagerPositionID, 0 AS n
         FROM tmpPeople
        UNION ALL
       SELECT RootID, RootName, d.PositionID, d.PreferredName, d.ManagerPositionID, 1
         FROM ChildrenCTE cte
         JOIN tmpPeople d ON d.ManagerPositionID = cte.PositionID
     )
SELECT RootID, RootName, SUM(n) AS nn
  FROM ChildrenCTE AS cte
 GROUP BY RootID, RootName
 ORDER BY SUM(n) DESC
;
```

With COUNT:

```sql
WITH ChildrenCTE AS (
       SELECT PositionID AS RootID, PreferredName AS RootName, PositionID, PreferredName, ManagerPositionID
         FROM tmpPeople
        UNION ALL
       SELECT RootID, RootName, d.PositionID, d.PreferredName, d.ManagerPositionID
         FROM ChildrenCTE cte
         JOIN tmpPeople d ON d.ManagerPositionID = cte.PositionID
     )
SELECT RootID, RootName, COUNT(*) - 1 AS children
  FROM ChildrenCTE AS cte
 GROUP BY RootID, RootName
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
;
```

The result:

| RootID | RootName | children |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person A | 17 |
| 3 | Person C | 11 |
| 2 | Person B | 4 |
| 11 | Person K | 4 |
| 4 | Person D | 3 |
| 5 | Person E | 2 |
| 6 | Person F | 2 |
| 12 | Person L | 2 |
| 7 | Person G | 1 |
| 8 | Person H | 1 |
| 13 | Person M | 1 |
| 14 | Person N | 1 |
| 9 | Person I | 0 |
| 10 | Person J | 0 |
| 15 | Person O | 0 |
| 16 | Person P | 0 |
| 17 | Person Q | 0 |
| 18 | Person R | 0 |

Comment: Sounds logical, but it double counts as the hierarchy grows bigger. For example, with another CTE on the real data, picking a manager and finding all their direct reports, produces 150 rows (including themselves.     This solution above to try count them gives a number of 300.

Comment: There is no doubling in the logic given.  But if you try to modify this SQL, you probably made a mistake.  This sounds like a new question or you don't understand the data.  Please mark this an answer or provide an update to the question with data (new inserts) to show a case which is not handled as you expect.

Comment: Thank Jon, I appreciate your taking the time to assist me. I have reworked the problem to be far more explicit, with a slightly broader sample dataset. The code is a direct copy and paste from my SSMS, and the results are too.

Comment: @Maxcot You were correct.  The original solution wasn't correct.  I've updated that logic.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that does the trick. I'm not sure I fully understand the logic of this CTE, but stackoverflow and people like you make it possible to overcome that barrier! Much appreciated.